# How to switch between clusters in Cockpit-Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cockpit

I am using `cockpit-kubernetes` to visually inspect my kubernetes cluster(s). My kubernetes config supports two clusters -- one local and one external on AWS. When I added an eternal cluster, `cockpit-kubernetes` made me "troubleshoot" to declare the new cluster, which I did. I could view the added cluster, no problem. But I am at a loss about how to switch back to view my local cluster.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is a view of my UI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you can't use multiple clusters with cockpit at the same time.
You need to have separate instance for every cluster you have.